# How To Write A Regular Expression For Specific Requirement?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working On Regular Expression in JavaScript, I tried all my possible ways but i couldn't get an answer for my requirement.

My requirement is, I need a regular expression, it should validate a string to be contained  at least one character, one capital letter, one number and one special character. They all should occur anywhere in the string, like "Kumar04@".

My work around is:

```
var regex= RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9][^\w]*$");
```

But it is validating only either one letter or one capital letter or one number, but I need at least one of each group.

Comment: Check [`var rx = /^(?=.*\W)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/pJ1iV3/2).

Comment: Did the below answer help you, Kumar?

Comment: Thanks For Quick Reply, the below answer correctly working in Online Regex  Builder, But it is not working in my workaround, I am Using Visual Studio 2010. Thanks and Regards, kumar.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\s\w]).*$/;
```